# Initial values for oscillations about a point problem (normal modes)

Tags: mathematical-physics, mathematical-modeling, classical-mechanics

I have the Lagrangian $L=\frac{1}{2}(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2) -7x^2+2xy-\frac{11}{2}y^2$. So the two equations of motion are $\ddot{x}+14x-2y=0$ and $\ddot{y}-2x+11y=0$. Hence the general solution (by using the normal modes method) is

$\vec{x}(t)=\begin{bmatrix}
           -2 \\
           1 \\
         \end{bmatrix}$$\big(\alpha_1\cos(\sqrt{15}t)+\beta_1\sin(\sqrt{15}t)\big) + \begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           2 \\
         \end{bmatrix}$$\big(\alpha_2\cos(\sqrt{10}t)+\beta_2\sin(\sqrt{10}t)\big)$.

But here I am asked to find the normal modes associated with oscillations about $x=y=0$. I suspect that this can be summaried by initial conditions for $\vec{x}(t)$ and $\vec{v}(t)$ but I don't know which ones.

Comment: Your solution is oscillating about $x = y =0$. Thus, it seems that you are done.

Answer (score 1):

As the movement is described by

$$
\ddot X = M\cdot X
$$

with $M = T\cdot \Lambda\cdot T^{-1}$ we have

$$
T^{-1}\cdot {\ddot X} = \ddot Z = \Lambda\cdot T^{-1}\cdot X = \Lambda\cdot Z
$$

so with a change of coordinates we have the equivalent system

$$
\ddot Z = \Lambda\cdot Z\Rightarrow \cases{\ddot z_1 = \lambda_1 z_1\\
\ddot z_2 = \lambda_2 z_2}
$$

and the normal/generator modes are

$$
\cases{
z_1 = \alpha_1\cos\sqrt{\lambda_1 t}+\beta_1\sin\sqrt{\lambda_1}t = \rho_1\cos(\sqrt{\lambda_1}t+\phi_1)\\
z_2 = \alpha_2\cos\sqrt{\lambda_2 t}+\beta_2\sin\sqrt{\lambda_2}t = \rho_2\cos(\sqrt{\lambda_2}t+\phi_2)}
$$